# Can multiple programs that require rfmon mode use the rfmon interface simultaneously?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

I'm using multiple programs that require the network card to be set in rfmon (monitor) mode (bettercap and OpenWIPS-ng, and sometimes aircrack-ng). I was just wondering, could these programs use the same network card in rfmon mode simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if they all need it set to the same parameters the whole time. But if one needs to change the channel or channel width or something, that could mess up what the other tools were trying to do. But if they're all just listening and need the interface set up the same way, they can all listen simultaneously.